# Trying to take only the lowest value for a unique key in SAS using PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS, I'm trying to make a table that has only 1 line for each unique key (*Apl_Key*). Unfortunately I have several score values (*SCOR_RSLT_RAW_SCOR*) for each unique key (*Apl_Key*); and would like to therefore just take the lowest score value for each key.

This is what part of what the table looks like without me trying to reduce it down:

[image]

And my code to try and change it to just the lowest score is:

[image]

Obviously this is not working. I'm not the most proficient SQL or SAS coder; so some help would be great!

Comment: Your question is about *one* table.  Your code references multiple tables.  That is confusing.  Also, you should include the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry. The picture of the code I put in, would produce the part of the output table I put in, if it didn't have the where statement. So it is all in one table

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach if you have the data in one table:

```
proc sql;
     select t.*
     from t
     where t.SCOR_RSLT_RAW_SCOR = (select min(t2.SCOR_RSLT_RAW_SCOR)
                                   from t t2
                                   where t2.apl_key = t.apl_key
                                  );
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using group by?

Here is an example for just pulling *apl_key* and it's associated minimum *SCOR_RSLT_RAW_SCOR*. You can extend the same logic to all your other variables in the select statement.

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select apl_key, min(SCOR_RSLT_RAW_SCOR)
from pl_mat.ECCVStable
group by apl_key;
quit;
```